# Invalid sorting in rows of laravel-datatables-oracle

Tags: laravel, angular-datatables

In my laravel 5.8 app using yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle 8 I make report sorted by 2 fields
and I see that results are shown in different order. My control action is :

```
public function get_check_out_history_dt_listing()
{
    $request     = request();
    $requestData = $request->all();
    $filter_customer = !empty($requestData['filter_customer']) ? $requestData['filter_customer'] : '';
    $filter_check_out_datepicker_from = !empty($requestData['filter_check_out_datepicker_from']) ? $requestData['filter_check_out_datepicker_from'] : '';
    $filter_check_out_datepicker_till = !empty($requestData['filter_check_out_datepicker_till']) ? $requestData['filter_check_out_datepicker_till'] : '';

    $filter_check_out_datepicker_from = str_replace(',', '', $filter_check_out_datepicker_from);
    if ( !empty($filter_check_out_datepicker_from) ) {
        $filter_check_out_datepicker_from = Carbon::createFromFormat('d M Y', $filter_check_out_datepicker_from)->format('Y-m-d' );
    }

    $filter_check_out_datepicker_till = str_replace(',', '', $filter_check_out_datepicker_till);
    if ( !empty($filter_check_out_datepicker_till) ) {
        $filter_check_out_datepicker_till = Carbon::createFromFormat('d M Y', $filter_check_out_datepicker_till)->format('Y-m-d' );
    }

    $checkOutsCollection = CheckIn
        ::orderBy('check_ins.paid_through_date', 'asc') // The 2 fields I make sorting
        ->orderBy('storage_spaces.number', 'asc')
        ->getByStatus('O')  // O=>Check Out
        ->getByPaidThroughDate($filter_check_out_datepicker_from, '>=')
        ->getByPaidThroughDate($filter_check_out_datepicker_till, '<=')
        ->whereRaw( 'NOT ISNULL(check_ins.paid_through_date) ')
        ->leftJoin( 'clients', 'clients.id', '=', 'check_ins.client_id' )
        ->leftJoin( 'storage_spaces', 'storage_spaces.id', '=', 'check_ins.storage_space_id' )
        ->where( 'clients.full_name', 'like' , '%' . $filter_customer .'%' )
        ->select(
            "check_ins.id",
            "check_ins.check_in_date",
            "check_ins.paid_through_date",
            "check_ins.vat",
            "check_ins.job_ref_no as check_ins_job_ref_no",
            "clients.full_name as client_full_name",
            "clients.address as client_address",
            "storage_spaces.number as storage_spaces_number",
            "storage_spaces.status as storage_spaces_status",
            "check_ins.insurance_vat as storage_insurance_vat",
            "check_ins.vat as storage_actual_storage_rent"
        )
        ->get();

    return Datatables
        ::of($checkOutsCollection)     /*  Set format/labels for specific columns  */
        ->editColumn('storage_spaces_status', function ($storageSpace) {
            if (empty($storageSpace->storage_spaces_status)) {
                return '';
            }
            return StorageSpace::getStorageSpaceStatusLabel($storageSpace->storage_spaces_status);
        })

        ->editColumn('storage_insurance_vat', function ($storageSpace) {
            if (empty($storageSpace->storage_insurance_vat)) {
                return '';
            }
            return $this->formatCurrencySum($storageSpace->storage_insurance_vat);
        })

        ->editColumn('storage_actual_storage_rent', function ($storageSpace) {
            if (empty($storageSpace->storage_actual_storage_rent)) {
                return '';
            }
            return $this->formatCurrencySum($storageSpace->storage_actual_storage_rent);
        })
        ->editColumn('check_in_date', function ($storageSpace) {
            if (empty($storageSpace->check_in_date)) {
                return '';
            }
            return $this->getCFFormattedDate($storageSpace->check_in_date);
        })
        ->editColumn('paid_through_date', function ($storageSpace) {
            if (empty($storageSpace->paid_through_date)) {
                return '';
            }
            return $this->getCFFormattedDate($storageSpace->paid_through_date);
        })
        ->make(true);
} // get_check_out_history_dt_listing
```

and in related js file I run :

```
checkOutHistory.prototype.checkOutHistoryDataLoad = function () {
    Mustache.tags = ["<%", "%>"];

    var columnsData = []
    // columnsData[columnsData.length] = {data: 'id', name: 'id'}
    columnsData[columnsData.length] = {data: 'storage_spaces_number', name: 'storage_spaces_number'}
    columnsData[columnsData.length] = {data: 'storage_spaces_status', name: 'storage_spaces_status'}
    columnsData[columnsData.length] = {data: 'client_full_name', name: 'client_full_name'}
    columnsData[columnsData.length] = {data: 'client_address', name: 'client_address'}
    columnsData[columnsData.length] = {data: 'check_ins_job_ref_no', name: 'check_ins_job_ref_no'}
    columnsData[columnsData.length] = {data: 'check_in_date', name: 'check_in_date'}
    columnsData[columnsData.length] = {data: 'storage_actual_storage_rent', name: 'storage_actual_storage_rent'}
    columnsData[columnsData.length] = {data: 'storage_insurance_vat', name: 'storage_insurance_vat'}
    columnsData[columnsData.length] = {data: 'paid_through_date', name: 'paid_through_date'}


    oTable = $('#get-check-out-history-dt-listing-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        autoWidth: false,
        language: {
            "processing": "Loading Check Out History..."
        },
        serverSide: true,
        "lengthChange": true,
        "lengthMenu": this_backendLengthMenuArray,
        ajax: {                          // report/get-check-out-history-dt-listing
            url: this_backend_home_url + '/admin/report/get-check-out-history-dt-listing',
            data: function (d) {
                d.filter_customer = $("#filter_customer").val();
                d.filter_check_out_datepicker_from = $("#filter_check_out_datepicker_from").val();
                d.filter_check_out_datepicker_till = $("#filter_check_out_datepicker_till").val();
            },
        }, // ajax: {

        columns: columnsData,

        "drawCallback": function (settings, b) {
            var span_check_out_histories_records_count_content = $("#span_check_out_histories_records_count").html()

            if (typeof span_check_out_histories_records_count_content != "undefined") {
                $("#span_check_out_histories_records_count").html( ". Shows " + settings.json.data.length + " of " + settings.json.recordsFiltered + " box rooms" )
            } else {
                var $label = $("<label>").text(". Shows " + settings.json.data.length + " of " + settings.json.recordsFiltered + " box rooms").attr({
                    id: 'span_check_out_histories_records_count',
                    name: 'span_check_out_histories_records_count'
                });

                $(".dataTables_length > label ").append( $label );
            }

            $(".dataTables_info").css("display", "none")
            if (settings.json.recordsTotal <= settings.aiDisplay.length) { // we need to hide pagination block
                $(".dataTables_paginate").css("display", "none")
            } else {  // we need to show pagination block
                $(".dataTables_paginate").css("display", "block")
            }

        },

    }); // oTable = $('#get-check-out-history-dt-listing-table').DataTable({

}
```

When I check sql-trace I see that all rows are returned in valid order I set with orderBy in my control.
That datatables changed ordering and I do not see why
I do not set any ordering anymore in datatables...
and how can I set it manually ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example from  https://datatables.net/reference/option/ordering

```
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "ordering": false
  } );
```

helped me!